# I need to capture all the dynamic values between the two slash symbol(i.e t-e-s-t-q-a) and replace the (-) symbol with empty space (i.e. t e s t q a)

Tags: jmeter, performance

need to capture dynamic values and replace with empty spaces replace the (-) symbol with empty space (i.e. t e s t q a).

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdl2m.png)

Comment: Hi @Guruganesh, we're going to need a lot more information to help you out - can you add some detail please, such as language, tools, research, etc.

Comment: need to capture all the dynamic values between the two slash symbol(i.e t-e-s-t-q-a) and replace the (-) symbol with empty space (i.e. t e s t q a).

For this task please use dummy sampler.

www.demoqa.com/t-e-s-t-q-a/
www.demoqa.com/t-e-s-t-q-b/
www.demoqa.com/t-e-s-t-q-c/ i had captured values using reg ex and i need repalce (-) with empty spaces using bean shell post processor

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a [regular expression extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to your request and extract all values (use -1 as match no as shown below)[image].
2. To the test plan add a beanshell sampler and add the following code.
   The code does replace - with empty space and puts inthe same variable as shown below

> int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Values_matchNr")); for(int
>   i=1;i<=count;i++) {
>
> String value=vars.get("Values_"+i); String value_replaced =
>   value.replaceAll("-", " "); vars.put("Values_"+i,value_replaced); }

[image]

You can use`${Values_1}`, `${Values_2}` and so on..

[image]

assume that,If you want to pass it as a parameter to the next request you can just add that variable as shown below

[image]

you can see in the results `t e s t q a` , `t e s t q b`, `t e s t q c` passed as parameters
[image]

For more information on bean shell please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)

Comment: ${Values_1}, ${Values_2}  where i can use these values , in script can u please tell me

Comment: You can use it anywhere in the script after replacing - with space..


Just like other JMeter variables..

Let me know your exact requirement i can suggest more appropriate answer..

What do you want to do after replacing - with space?

Comment: ur anser is correct rohit but can u put scrrenshot of ${value_1}  in script please

Comment: I have updated the answer please have a look, Hope it helps ,and if it's correct you can accept the answer !!! i hope

Comment: SUPER GREAT ROHIT u r super talented tq so muchhhhhhhhhhh may god bless u

Comment: GET http://localhost/test?value 1=t-e-s-t-q-a&value 2=t-e-s-t-q-b&value 3=t-e-s-t-q-c like this came in http reqst in result how can do rohit  localhost/test??? got error

Comment: GET localhost/test?value 1=t-e-s-t-q-a&value 2=t-e-s-t-q-b&value 3=t-e-s-t-q-c like this came in http reqst in result how can do rohit localhost/test??? got error can u pls tell me how to get  localhost/test?value ??

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) on next available opportunity

1. Given you have response data like:

   ```
   some text
   www.demoqa.com/t-e-s-t-q-a/
   www.demoqa.com/t-e-s-t-q-b/ 
   www.demoqa.com/t-e-s-t-q-c/
   some other text
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns this data and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def matcher = prev.getResponseDataAsString() =~ "/(.+?)/"
   def counter = 1;
   while (matcher.find()) {
      vars.put('somevar_' + counter,matcher.group(1).replace("-"," "))
      counter++;
   }
   ```
3. It will produce the following JMeter Variables:

   ```
   somevar_1=t e s t q a
   somevar_2=t e s t q b
   somevar_3=t e s t q c
   ```

   You will be able to refer them as `${somevar_1}`, `${somevar_2}`, etc. where required.

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Matchers for Regular Expressions](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)